# Understanding surjectivity proof of $f(n)=2^n$.

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

Working on the book: Richard Hammack. "Book of Proof" (p. 252)

> 3. Let $B=\{2^n:n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Show that the function $f: \mathbb{Z}\to B$, defined as $f(n) = 2^n$ is bijective. Then find $f^{-1}$.

The author proves surjectivity:

> The function $f$ is surjective as follows. Suppose $b \in \mathbb{B}$. By definition of $B$ this means $b = 2^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $f(n) = 2^n = b$

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I think this does not proves surjectivity. Instead, would be neccesary to take an arbitrary element $b \in B$, and show there exists an element $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(a) = b$. In this case, letting $a = \log_2(b)$, we see
$$
f(a)=f(\log_2(b))=2^{\log_2(b)}=b
$$

Is my observation correct ?

Comment: Did you mean $f(n)=2^n$ where you typed $f(n)=2n$?

Comment: Your $b$  has the form $2^n$.

Comment: "Instead, would be neccesary to take an arbitrary element b∈B, and show there exists an element a∈Z such that f(a)=b"  But that is *exactly* what the author *DID* do.  $b\in \{2^n|n\in \mathbb Z\}$ so $b$ is some $2^n$ for some integer $n$.  So *take* that integer and then $f(n) = 2^n = b$.

Comment: Your proof is not quite correct.  You haven't used the definition of $B$ anywhere.  In fact you need use it to show that $a = \log_2(b) \in \mathbb{Z}$; but that would just be writing the author's proof in a slightly more complicated way.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Perhaps I'm missing something, but I think this does not proves surjectivity. Instead, would be neccesary to take an arbitrary element b∈B, and show there exists an element a∈Z such that f(a)=b.

That is exactly what the author did do!

S/he picked $b$ to be an arbitrary element of $B$.  By the definition of $B$ all the elements of $B$ are of the form $2^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z$.

So s/he just let $a$ be that $n$.  She just didn't want to spend the $25$ cents to buy a second variable.  (If she asked me, I know a place where she can get variables wholesale.....)

> In this case, letting a=log2(b),

That's *one* way to get the $a$.... but you have to then prove that $\log_2 b\in \mathbb Z$[1].

But another way to get that $a$ is to say $b = 2^n$ for some $n$, so let $a = n$.

That way you can save on the cost of the function turning handcranks.  Variables are cheap but the function turning handcranks are mucho bucks if you don't need them.

====

[1] How would you prove $\log_2 b \in \mathbb Z$?

Well, really the only way I see is:  ... Let $b \in B$.  Then there is an integer $n$ so that $b = 2^n$.  So $\log_2 b =\log_2 2^n = n$ which is an integer.

Comment: Much appreciated, @fleablood. I had the wrong impression that proving surjectivity was a difficult matter and it seemed to me that he wasn't proving anything. May I ask: can you point me to a proof of surjectivity that isn't so "direct", so I can compare ?

Comment: Um....  Okay prove that $f(x) = \frac x{x+1}$ $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,1)$ is surjective.  For every $b \in (0,1)$ we must prove there is an $x; x > 0$ so that $\frac x{x+1} = b$. Well if $\frac x{x+1} = b$ then $x=bx + b$ so $x-bx=b$ and $x(1-b)=b$ As $b< 1$ then $1-b\ne 0$ so $x = \frac b{1-b}$ And $0< b < 1$ we have $1-b > 0$ and as $b>0$ we have $x =\frac b{1-b} >0$.  So $f(\frac b{1-b})=\frac {\frac b{1-b}}{ \frac b{1-b} +1}=b$. So $f$ is surjective.... It's only in this case the *way* that the set $B$ was defined made the problem simple and utterly obvious.

Comment: BTW... Had the function *not* been $\mathbb Z \to B$ but had been $g:\mathbb R\to (0,\infty)$ via $g(x) = 2^x$ then proving $g$ is surjective would be to take an arbitrary $b \in (0, \infty)$ and show there must be an $x \in \mathbb R$ so that $2^x= b$ we'd... take $x =\log_2 b$ to show that.... Perhaps that is they real issue.  This *isn't* a function from real domain to real codomain.  The domain is $\mathbb Z$ and the codomain is.... well, just happens to be $B=\{2^n|n\in \mathbb Z\} = f(\mathbb Z)$ the *image* of $f$.  By the way $B$ was defined there was nothing really to prove.

Comment: Your example and last comment made all the difference for understanding this. Thank you so much, @fleablood !

Answer (score 0):

Both proofs are correct. the difference is that you element $ b$ in $ B $, has been written as $2^n$.
You can also say :

$ B $ is exactly the range of $ f$, so $ f$ from $\Bbb Z $ to $ B $ is by construction surjective.

on the other hand,
$$f(n)=f(m) \implies$$
$$2^n=2^m\implies$$
$$2^{n-m}=1\implies$$
$$n-m=0\implies n=m $$
$ f$ is then injective and bijective and as you wrote
$$f^{-1}(b)=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(2)}$$

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question the OP had...